# Do I need to call startRefresh7 on a newly item just added with startRefreshItemOnAddition=true

Tags: yodlee

or can I skip the **startRefresh7**, which will save good amount of time as network traffic is time consuming.
And if yes, just to be complete, this means that I can go straight to **isItemRefreshing** to check if/when the refresh finishes.

Is the above possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is important to handle MFA. So in additemForContentService1 API you need to pass the "startRefreshItemOnAddition" as false. Then you need to call the startRefresh7 with correct refreshMode depending on what type of site you are trying to link.

If you don't want to implement MFA then you can just pass "startRefreshItemOnAddition" as true and then continue with isItemRefreshing.

But I will strongly recommend implementation of MFA as well.

Comment: As I thought. You see, on some use cases, such as a closed list of sites (containers, to be more accurate), I will know in advance that there's no MFA involved. I see that in those cases indeed I can go directly to **isItemRefreshing**. Thanks for the swift reply.